# Linear regression with heavy-tailed gradient noise and generalized CLT

Tags: pr.probability

I want to investigate the distribution of the stochastic gradients when applying SGD to linear regression, in very simple but non-trivial situations. For dimension $1$ and when estimating only the slope, the stochastic gradient in step $n$ takes the form

$$G_n(\theta) = D(\theta) X_n^2 + X_n \epsilon_n,$$

where $D$ is a function of the current model parameter $\theta$, $X_n$ is a feature (independent variable) and $\epsilon_n$ is the corresponding residual, and independent of $X_n$. We assume $\mathbb E[X_n] = \mathbb E[\epsilon_n] = 0$ and that $(X_n)_n$ and $(\epsilon_n)_n$ are independent iid sequences.

If $\mathbb E|X_n|^4 < \infty$, then using the CLT we can essentially write

$$G_n(\theta) \epsilon_n \approx D(\theta) + \Sigma(\theta) Z$$

for some Gaussian rv. $Z$, in the sense that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N\Sigma(\theta)}} \sum_{n=1}^N (G_n(\theta) - D(\theta)) \Rightarrow \mathcal N(0,1),$$
as $N \to \infty$.
In particular, if $X_n, \epsilon_n \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, then $\Sigma(\theta) = 2 D(\theta)^2 + 1$.

Now, what happens if $X_n^2$ is heavy-tailed? In particular, we may consider $X_n$ to have symmetric $\alpha$-stable distribution with scale parameter $\sigma = 1$. Then (if I'm not mistaken) the CDF of $X_n^2$ has tails of the form $x^{-\alpha/2}$, so I expect we have

$$D(\theta) X_n^2  \approx D(\theta) + \text{?} Z,$$
where $Z$ is $\alpha/2$-stable.
But what can we say about $G_n(\theta)?$ We are free to choose a different distribution for $\epsilon_n$ for simplicity, but it should be centered and non-deterministic to avoid the trivial situation where all data points are collinear.

The case of Gaussian $\epsilon_n$ seems complicated. For $\frac12(\epsilon + 1)$ a symmetric Bernoulli (that is $\epsilon$ is symmetric Rademacher) the tails of the CDF of seem to be determined by the tails of the CDF of $D(\theta) X_n^2 + X_n$, which still seems complicated.

Is there a situation where $X_n^2$ is heavy-tailed and $\epsilon_n$ centered and non-deterministic where the generalized CLT can be applied to $(G_n)_n$ and we can explicitely determine $\alpha$?